# Json.fromJson not working for Int or Double

Tags: json, playframework

How can I resolve following implicit conflict? I converted a Double to JsValue using Json.toJson. The reverse process is not working. There is an implicit conflict.

```
scala> val doublejsv = Json.toJson(4.1)
doublejsv: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = 4.1

scala> Json.fromJson(doublejsv)
<console>:21: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both object IntReads in trait DefaultReads of type play.api.libs.json.Reads.IntReads.type
 and object ShortReads in trait DefaultReads of type play.api.libs.json.Reads.ShortReads.type
 match expected type play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]
       Json.fromJson(doublejsv)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit type:

```
val double = Json.fromJson[Double](doublejsv)
```